# Can't create Columns in my WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I have this code for my very **very** basic WPF Project.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">   

<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid>
```

However, the column definition line gives me an error:

> Error 1   Cannot add instance of type 'ColumnDefinition' to a collection of type 'UIElementCollection'. Only items of type 'UIElement' are allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to enclose it in a ColumnDefinitions collection.

```
<Grid Height="27">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Adding row definitions works the same way.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="LeftColumn"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

I think this is what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML, this notation:

```
<Container>
    <ContentItem />
</Container>
```

Is shorthand for this:

```
<Container>
    <Container.Children>
        <ContentItem />
    </Container.Children>
</Container>
```

The error is saying the grid will take UIElement items for children, but not ColumnDefinition items. This is because of the `<Container.Children>` implied in the shorthand notation being used.

As other answers have stated, ColumnDefinition items need to be children of `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` for the XAML to be valid. However, it's good to know that if the markup were like this:

```
<Grid>
    <ColumnDefinition />
    <Grid.Children>
        ...
    </Grid.Children>
</Grid>
```

Then you would also have a *The property 'Children' is set more than once* build error, because it's XAML syntax that makes `<Container.Children>` be implied in the shorthand notation. That's why `<ColumnDefinition>` items need to be explicitly enclosed in the `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>` collection, otherwise the compiler tries to take `<ColumnDefinition>` under an implied `<Grid.Children>` tag which expects items derived from UIElement, hence the error.