# how do i insert a stack panel into a grid?

Tags: wpf, grid, stackpanel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't create Columns in my WPF Grid. [Newbie]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1719093/cant-create-columns-in-my-wpf-grid-newbie)

i tried to insert the stack panel into grid using the following:

```
    <TabItem Header ="XML PARSING" Name="Tabitem5" Visibility="Visible">
        <Grid>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <StackPanel Name="stack1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Button Height="23" Name="XmlappendButton" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="XmlappendButton_Click">Update</Button>
                </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
```

I can't seem to be able to load the design view after this. Any help is appreciated

EDIT:
Sorry the error is:
 `Error 1   A value of type 'ColumnDefinition' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'.`

Answer (score 0):

You are wrongly defining your columns and rows. You need to have your `<ColumnDefinition />`'s inside the the grid ColumnDefinitions property. You access that property through `<Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>`. Apply the same logic for rows which have to be declared inside the Grid's RowDefinitions property. Here's the corrected sample:

```
<TabItem Header ="XML PARSING" Name="Tabitem5" Visibility="Visible">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Name="stack1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                    <Button Height="23" Name="XmlappendButton" Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="XmlappendButton_Click">Update</Button>
                </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Tabitem>
```